# How to get three columns and two rows (1 x 2 x 2) with flexbox

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I want to achieve the following result with Flex if possible. Know how to get that done with CSS, but not quite familiar with Flex. The reason why I want to do that in flex it to force myself write concise and more maintainable codes.

[image]

```css
.banner {
  width: 20%;
  height: 100%;
  position: relative;
  float: left;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.item {
  height: 50%;
  width: 33.33%;
  float: left;
  position: relative;
}

.inner-item-block {
  height: 100%;
  width: 80%;
  float: left;
  position: relative;
}

.inner-line {
  border-right: 1px solid #dedede;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #dedede;
  height: 100%;
  position: relative;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center; /* center child elements */
}
```

```html
<div class="item-block">
  <div class="banner banner3">
  </div>
  <div class="inner-item-block">
    <div class="item">
      <div class="inner-line">
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="item">
      <div class="inner-line">
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="item">
      <div class="inner-line">
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="item">
      <div class="inner-line">
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Please review and comment on my answer, and let me know if something is unclear or missing. If not, then it would be great if you could accept the answer that helped you the most.

Answer (score 1):

If you can set fixed height on parent element then you can do this with Flexbox. You can set `flex-direction: column` with `flex-wrap: wrap` and make first child element take 100% of height.

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
body {
  margin: 0;
}
.parent {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  height: 100vh;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}
.parent > div {
  flex: 0 0 50%;
  width: 33.33%;
  border: 1px solid black;
}
div.first {
  flex: 0 0 100%;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <div class="first">First</div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
</div>
```

New option to create this layout is **Grid-layout**, you just have to set `grid-row: span 2` on first child element.

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
body {
  margin: 0;
}
.parent {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(3, 1fr);
  grid-auto-rows: minmax(100px, auto);
}
.parent > div {
  border: 1px solid black;
}
div.first {
  grid-row: span 2;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <div class="first">First</div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div>
  <div class="first">First</div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Great answer. One more thing, how can I get a responsive height that will grow and shrink proportionally.

Comment: As i said with flexbox you need to set fixed height on parent with grid it is responsive https://jsfiddle.net/Lg0wyt9u/2105/