# How to move last flex-item on a new column in flexbox column layout?

Tags: css, flexbox

How can I get a column flex layout to wrap the last item into a new column. I do not wish to set a fixed height on the container.

So below I want `.image` on a new column row.

HTML:

```
<div class="container">   
    <div class="title"></div>
    <div class="text"></div>
    <div class="image"></div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.container {
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    flex-direction: column;
}
```

Comment: Take a look at this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45442974/how-to-get-three-columns-and-two-rows-1-x-2-x-2-with-flexbox/45443186#45443186

Comment: That question refers to fixing the height of parent which I cannot do.

Comment: Then you can't...the column needs to know **when** to wrap and it can't do that without a known height in flexbox.